# Cannot set a field value of a Django form in views

Tags: python, django, forms, django-views, django-forms

I am making a todo website in which different users can sign in and have their separate todo lists, but when a user signs in and adds a task to the list that task does not get assigned to any user, so despite being present on the database it does not show up on the user's list.

I am trying to assign the form object(`task_form`) a user after the form submission, I think that is the issue but I have no idea what else to try.

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='todo:login')
def task_add(request):
    if(request.method == "POST"):
        task_form = AddTask(request.POST)
        if(task_form.is_valid()):

            task_form.cleaned_data['user'] = request.user #trying to assign a user after all the data has been populated

            task_form.save()
            return redirect('todo:index')
    return render(request,'todo/task_add.html')
```

**template(task_add.html)**

```
{% block body %}
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title"></p>
        <p><label for="desc">Description</label>
        <input type="text" name="desc"></p>
        <p><label for="start_time">Time</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" name="start_time"></p>
        <p><label for="completed">Complete</label>
        <input type="radio" name="completed"></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False,null=True,blank=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**forms.py**

```
class AddTask(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `.user` attribute of the `.instance` wrapped in the form:

```
@login_required(login_url='todo:login')
def task_add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        task_form = AddTask(request.POST)
        if task_form.is_valid():
            task_form.instance.user = request.user
            task_form.save()
            return redirect('todo:index')
    return render(request,'todo/task_add.html')
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked!!! But, why is my method not working?

Comment: @PoseidonBroger: because if the field is not in `fields`, Django will skip it: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/models.py#L444-L445

Comment: Also you've set thje user = blank & null = True meaning it's optional. So it wont complain when you save a task without it.  The reason yours didn't work is your didn't change it on the form, you were accessing the cleaned_data and I don't think you can change that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I changed my fields as such - `fields = ('user','title','desc','start_time','completed')` and it still did not seem to work. I think we cannot change cleaned_data.

Comment: @AppHandwerker I think so too

Comment: It's worth noting that, as you have user as optional. you could also have saved the form. Which returns the model object. then set the user on the object and saved it again or called .update(user=request.user) all viable options. However @PoseidonBroger approach means you only do a single save, worth considering if you're scaling up.

Comment: @PoseidonBroger: it will not work since in that case you should also render a HTML field for that author. So without this, the form will simply not be successful, so `form.is_valid()` will be `False`.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Ok, Got it. Thank You